# Permissions needed for code downloaded after app install

Tags: android, android-permissions, dexclassloader

Android's developer documentation requires listing the permissions needed for an app in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. My question relates to the situation when I want provide an updated feature to the app, not via app store update, but via downloading code (e.g. JAR) and using a `DexClassLoader`. If I need to download code, then do I need to plan ahead and list permissions that the downloaded code would also need in the `AndroidManifest.xml` ?